# Elegant design for workflow with feedback mechanism

Tags: java, class, oop, database-design

I'm looking for a way to model my Java application code as good as possible, but I can't wrap my head around a good design.

I'm trying to import data, process it into a database and send feedback afterwards. I'll also save the state of the import process as an entity in a database, because feedback about the process is an important factor. I came up with this design, but I don't feel good about it.

```
public interface FeedbackService {

    void startingImport();

    void fetchingDataSuccessful(int amountObjectsFetched);

    void fetchingDataUnsuccessful(Exception e);

    void addSuccessfulObjectProcess(Object processedObject);

    void addUnsuccessfulObjectProcess(Object processedObject);

    void processingDataSuccessful(int amountObjectsProcessed);

    void processingDataUnsuccessful(Exception e);

    void sendFeedback();

    void finishImport();
}
```

A big concern I have about this design, is that you have different states in which only certain functions can be called. I read somewhere that it's terrible design when your methods depend on calling other methods first. Also, this would call for the State design pattern, which might be overkill for what is basically an extended logging library.

I tried to solve this problem by using the Template pattern, that way the workflow and the logging with their sequential dependencies are handled by the super class, while the sub classes can handle the data specific code (processing products, processing catalogs, etc).

```
public void handle(){
    registration.startImport();

    try {
        int amount = fetchData();
        registration.fetchingDataSuccessful(amount);
        try {
            for (Object o : getData()) {
                if (handleObject(o)) {
                    registration.addSuccessfulObjectProcess(o);
                } else {
                    registration.addUnsuccessfulObjectProcess(o);
                }
            }
            registration.processingDataSuccessful(getData().size());

        } catch (DataHandlingException e) {
            registration.processingDataUnsuccessful(e);
        }

    } catch (DataFetchingException e) {
        registration.fetchingDataUnsuccessful(e);
    }

    registration.sendFeedback();
}
```

*fetchData(), getData() and handleObject() would be abstract methods implement by the sub class*

However, now my code leaks, especially with the add(Un)successfulObjectProcess method and the getData() method. Since this one needs to be executed inside the loop, I need to pull the loop (and the data) to the super class, or, alternatively, I need to pass the feedbackservice into the sub class. Both ways are not really what I want. Especially since the handling of a list of objects might be more complicated than looping once over every element. (sometimes we need to fetch references, build trees, etc)

I feel like I'm over complicating this design, but I don't want to write one long spaghetti function to just make it work. I'm looking for ideas, previous experiences and feedback about how this should be tackled.

Comment: don't know if it is possible in Java, but in .NET I will use a IEnumerable / yield pattern. An external enumerator would consume each state of your workflor represente each by a single class. A 'done' callback would let the consumer to move to the next step. Each phase can return some result to drive the next yielded action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, "feedback"  is a cross-cutting concern, which is not part of core functionality).  Consider using AOP, as depicted below. That way you will keep your non-core code, i.e sending feedback, separate from core functionality.

Perhaps you can make an interface IDataImporter, make an around aspect that covers all methods in that interface. Create an abstract class that implements that interface, override appropriate methods in concrete-subclasses as required.

See attached image.
[image: Using AOP for cross-cutting concern]

Comment: Assuming that processData has various implementations for various 'entities', how do I handle that? 

I was thinking about creating a return type List<ProcessResult> that the AOP would catch, but I'm mixing the import logic with the feedback logic again to fabricate that list and return it...

Comment: An alternative would be to create a specific AOP wrapper for every implementation. That way I can finetune every feedback for the different implementations, such as a) processing one entity after another or b) processing a whole hierarchy. However, now I'm dependent on the specific implementation of IDataImporter, which can't be a good thing either.

Comment: AOP can intercept return type parameters, and you can get the "list size" etc. Your challenge is to articulate the solution as generic as possible for cleaner AOP-feedback. Reading about AOP for few hours, will give you more ideas to engineer - especially for return-parameter intercepting that you are interested.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I meant was: normally the processdata would not return anything, because that isn't part of its requirement. However, in order for AOP to provide feedback, there would need to be something returned (that can be intercepted), thus mixing the two requirements again. Another way AOP could provide feedback would be by diving deeper, and intercepting calls  of the actual implementation of the processData, and providing feedback based on that. Neither solution looks really good to me. (but AOP still looks better than my solution)

Comment: To minimize dependency; Let's say after *any* IDataImporterimpl method call you have some status. In your case if status is a "message string", then it can be set in IDataImporter.status within each method call. eg : void processData(){ status = null; //dosomething ; status = "x objects failed, y obj success"}. in your aopIntercept(){ if (status !=null) register.senndFeedback(status)}. That way you can make the aop not depend on return type, but just have data processors comply with contract IDataImporter(.status).